# Actuator to control steam valve

Tags: actuator, valve

I have a steam radiator at home and it has a valve similar to the picture below.

[image]

Please note that the valve doesn't have grooves on top to attach things to.

I want to build something to turn it on and off depending on the temperature at certain points in the room.

I have that taken care of but cannot find a way to attach a actuator(actuator is the right word in the context I guess?) to turn the valve in both directions.

Also It is a rented apartment so I would like to avoid making any modifications to the radiator itself.

Comment: There's no screw on the valve that lets you change the manipulator on the top? Normally that valves require a high torque, and so the mechanical join should be up to that torque.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I just checked and yes the manipulator can be removed!!Also the valve seems to be fairly free and requires very less effort to open and close.Even with the manipulator removed, what am I supposed to replace it with?

Comment: well that's good, I added an answer then.

Comment: If you don't have the ability to machine a part to fit, a hacky way is to buy a similar manipulator in a plumbing/hw shop and glue a gear or a pulley to it.  You can then mount the entire "assembly" on.  If this isn't clear I can try to draw it up...

Comment: @GuySirton I have the ability to machine simple parts.I would like to see that assembly drawing you mentioned here.Thanks.

Comment: How many degrees rotation does this valve need from full-on to full-off?

Comment: It's more than 360 degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, being the manipulator removable, so you can attach other thing to the valve shaft, you have so much options.

## Mechanical coupling

You could use a coupled rotary actuator to the shaft by the means of a shaft coupler. There's many types, this is a [simple one](https://c10645061.ssl.cf2.rackcdn.com/product/icongo/icg_39276_motorshaftcoupler.jpg), but you probably would not get the actuator axle full aligned with the valve shaft, so a coupler that permits some misalignment is desirable, like these:

[rubber shaft coupler http://www.abssac.co.uk/uploads/products/cat_pp651_coupling%20jaw%202.jpg](http://www.abssac.co.uk/uploads/products/cat_pp651_coupling%20jaw%202.jpg)

Every coupler has its specifications and types of misalignment it will support.

You can use a belt or chain transmission too. Then you need to attach a pulley or sprocket to the valve axle.

**Chain and sprocket transmission**

[image: chain and sprocket transmission]

**Synchronous belt transmission**

[image: Synchronous belt transmission]

A possible problem with these two option is the lateral force the transmission could put on the valve shaft, as it has not made to support this, it probably will wear. <sup>One way to overcome this is to use a shaft coupler to a bearing with the transmission, so the lateral force will be supported by the bearing.</sup>

## Electro-mechanical actuator

For actuating the valve, you can use a couple of options.

- A stepper motor.
- A DC brushed-motor with a reduction gearbox like this

[image: DC brushed-motor with gearbox show]

<sup>The gears are show for illustration purposes, they are normally enclosed.</sup>

There's many types of reduction gearbox too, I will not extend into this on this answer.

You probably need some way of knowing the position of the valve shaft (feedback). It can be a multi-turn potentiometer for simple analog output.

## RC servo motor

If the valve needs less than 1 turn you can try to use an **RC servo-motor**, they have a DC-brushed motor, a reduction gearbox, a potentiometer for feedback, and a control circuit. You then feed with the angle position in a signal modulated by a technique know as PWM. Along the fact that the valve will operate at less than a 360° angle, you need to be sure the torque of the **RC servo motor** will be superior to the needed. Also metal gears and shaft will provide a more robust system, considering the torque.

## Assembly

[image: assembly]

<sup>@DiegoCNascimento the image can be used with credits</sup>

Here's a final assembly possibility. You should be sure the pipe could support the forces involved with a safety margin, if not, use the *wall mount* supports.

---

Note: some valves main axles will go up or down when rotated, if this is the case the mechanical coupler should support this.

**I do not assume any responsibility by any damage or injure in the mounting of this, the user should have plenty attention he/she is working with high-temperature and high-pressure parts that can pose danger.**

Comment: Great ideas.  I would avoid the coupling due to alignment issues, as you mention.  You can also use a largeish gear and a smaller drive gear.  Do you have some ideas though about how the OP can mount his motor?

Comment: @GuySirton thanks. I tried to use images for the transmission that showed the reduction in the sprocket or pulley :) Maybe a bit more clear. Anyway I will try to avoid this because of lateral force on the valve axis, so I think a coupler will be more interessing, I don't think aligning it will be dificult, just making a support that can be adjusted, but there's one thing I forget at writing I will add later, that is some valves axis tend to go up or down, if it the case a shaft coupler that tolerate this misalignment would solve the issue. I will try to add a idea for the support later.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Excellent answer.However I searched online but couldn't find a coupler.Perhaps a link would be great.Also I would like to know more about adding a support for the motor.I have access to a small workshop and can machine simple parts.Thanks for helping out though.

Comment: @Stevelrwin well I search for _shaft coupler_ will return lots of options, should not be difficult to get one. I will try to post anything about the support

Comment: Well, now there is a sketch of the assembly.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento That is just perfect.I have a high torque stepper motor lying around.Along with a pot , this assembly is going to be perfect!Thanks a lot for the meticulous sketch and answer.+1 for the disclaimer :)

Comment: You might consider a bevel or worm gear, they appear to fit this problem better, http://www.fi.edu/time/Journey/Time/Escapements/geartypes.html

Comment: A rack and pinion gear could allow you to 'hide' the assembly behind the radiator, a hypoid gear would allow offset from the center, and the harmonic drive could be mounted outside your valve for a clean assembly, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gear

Comment: @ChuckCottrill did you read about the harmonic drive? Look at their cost and the small number of manufacturers. I think there's just two. Also making the gearing itself doesn't seems a more easy way, this requires access to good materials, and specialized machinery. The more realistic you said is the worm gear, if it has a motor with it then it could use, but they are less efficient than planetary ones.

Answer (score 1):

**If the valve has enough traction with a rubber band<sup>1</sup>**, you can use one to control the valve as in the image below.

[image]

To make sure the rubber band doesn't start falling over time due to gravity, you could attach a half-circular plate under the valve, so the rubber band wouldn't slowly slide down as it would rest on that plate. Note that the amount of the pressure on the plate should be very small, since the rubber band is quite stretched to provide enough stretch for rotation, so a not so strong glue might do the trick for that plate.

<sup>1</sup> This both depends on the material it's made of and quite importantly, how much torque is required to turn the valve.

Comment: Well, I think that is really difficult for these valves. I don't know these, but by the OP post, I think they require a large amount of torque. Also my suggestion to the drawing: The motor should be put in smaller diameter than the manipulator of the valve and near it, this would put more rubber on the circumference of the valve. Also too much lateral force and the valve could wear fast.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento, thanks for the pointers. I'm actually a software programmer, so my knowledge of mechanics is rather limited.